# Ubuntu turning off every 30 seconds

Tags: nvidia, shutdown, restart

I recently installed ubuntu on a brand-new Razer laptop. After installing, there were no problems for about two hours. All of a sudden, Ubuntu keeps turning itself off about every 30 seconds. I would try to look at syslogs but I barely have any time. I’m on Ubuntu 20.04. Should I try to get in quickly? I really don’t know at this point.

Comment: Is your laptop sitting flat on a desk or blanket? If so, let that thing breathe. Heat is a very serious problem for many high-performing systems. Be sure to check that you have power management tools in place and that the system is not running too hot when idle.

Comment: Also a wrongly configured power management could be the reason for your problem.